# How to set topMargin in percentage of superview in autolayout in storyboard?

Tags: ios, ios-autolayout

How to set `topMargin` in percentage of superview in `autolayout` in storyboard?
how does it works relative to second object when multiplier & constant changes of top margin constraint?

Answer (score 0):

Probably would be better to set *Vertically in Container* and adjust multiplayer on this constraint. If this isn't good enough for your purposes, you can add empty view on the place where dynamic top margin should be and set its height constraint equal to container and adjust multiplier as well.

Comment: i know how to do it with vertically center constraint.but i would like to achieve it with top constraint as well.can anyone help in topmargin constraint?Thanks in advance

Comment: Doesn't empty view with dynamic height suit your purpose?

Comment: There are multiple UI controls which are differencing on top margin with percentage.I don't want to give empty views for all object in a superview to set according top margin.please suggest any other better option.

Comment: [Please check out this documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/AutolayoutPG/AnatomyofaConstraint.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010853-CH9-SW1)
One of the things it says:
    **You cannot constrain a size attribute to a location attribute.**
and
    **You cannot use a nonidentity multiplier (a value other than 1.0) with location attributes.**
The only way to achieve your goal is to change top margin constant value runtime, when you know your superview size. If it's not good enough for you as well, please rethink your autolayout.

Answer (score 0):

if u take a one button and connected to top layout margin. there u selected constant 20 and default multiplier 1.

button.top = 1 * top layout guide .bottom +20  this shows when u select that top constraint . if u change that multiplier to any value, it wont effect because top layout guide is 0 , so multiply that value with any value that gives 0.So here it add only constant value.

Answer (score 0):

This was really a question from a long time ago and didn't want to bother you guys, but I had the same situation and I used a weird but workable way to achieve. I hope to leave my records so that people who encounter the same problem later can solve it smoothly.

1. Create an auxiliary view in your IB as subview
2. Add constraints to this auxiliary view : top/left/right margin to superview and set constants to zero.
3. **Both select auxiliary view and your superview** in IB, then add new constraint makes auxiliary view's height equals to your superview
4. Change auxiliary view's height constraint's multiplier to the percentage you want, in this example I set 0.28 multiplier to superview's height. **Now you have a view with height sets to your desired percentage**.
5. Go to find your target subview, add top margin constraint to this **auxiliary view**, and set constant to zero.

[image: Auxiliary view as a percentage ruler]

Finally, if you have some more elegant implementation please discuss below. :)